# Question regarding IBIS models

Tags: simulation, impedance, output, model, ibis

I have the IBIS models for this [SY75603](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/TCG/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/SY75602A-02B-03A-03B-04A-04B-2-4-Outputs-Ultra-Low-Additive-Jitter-PCIe-1-2-3-4-5-Clock-Buffer-DS20006508.pdf) PCIe clock buffer IC.

However, the available IBIS model is only for the SY75603A with 85 Ω outputs; I'm using the SY75603B with 100 Ω outputs.

[image]

What should I do to get the IBIS model for the 100 Ω output part?

Is there something I can modify in the available IBIS model (SY75603A) so that I can use it for the 100 Ω output part?

Comment: There are no IBIS models available for any SY75603 chip. Where did you get it? Why not ask manufacturer for documentation?

Comment: Looking at section 4.2 of the datasheet, you can likely just add 15Ω to the parasitic resistance value for each output pin.  If your IBIS model uses a single package parasitic value instead of separate ones for each pin, it'll be a little more complicated.  It's hard to say more without seeing the IBIS model itself.  Also, if you're using the IBIS model in a platform which lets you define explicit additional resistors (like SPICE), you can just do that instead.